# Patch in pgflplots delimited by a function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following code, which makes me a parabola in a axis, and I would like to fill the region below the parabola (staying in the axis). It seems that it should be possible with plot and patch, but I did not find the solution. Could you help me please?

THE CODE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{My Line Style/.style={smooth, thick, samples=400}}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.60]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, xmin=-3.5, xmax = 3.5, ymin=-5.1, ymax = 3,xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
  ytick={-5,...,3}]
    \addplot[My Line Style, color=lightgray,  variable=\t, domain=-3.5:3.5]({\t},{\t^2-0.5});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}\end{document}
```

[image: The result]

The result should look like:
[image: result expected]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one possibility how to do it. For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use `axis cs:' coordinates by
        % default for tikz commands
        compat=1.11,
        My Line Style/.style={
            smooth,
            thick,
            samples=400,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xmin=-3.5,
        xmax=3.5,
        ymin=-5.1,
        ymax=3,
        xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
        ytick={-5,...,3},
        % use this so the axis is drawn on top of the everything
        axis on top,
    ]
        % first draw the fill stuff
        \addplot [
            My Line Style,
            draw=none,
            fill=lightgray!25,
            domain=-3.5:3.5,
            % restrict the y values to the maximum y axis value
            restrict y to domain*=-5.1:3,
        ] {x^2-0.5}
            % continue the path to close it
            |- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
        ;
        % and on top of that the line
        \addplot [
            My Line Style,
            draw=lightgray,
            domain=-3.5:3.5,
        ] {x^2-0.5}
        ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems nice. But it does not compile here. I get the following error: "./sampleplot.tex:13: Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.11' unknown in key '/pgfp
lots/compat/anchors'. I am going to ignore this key.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13     }
          
?"  In fact, removing the "compat"  line, it works.

Comment: Interesting. May I ask which version of PGFPlots you have (you can see it in the LOG file)? Just commenting/deleting the `compat` line *seems* to work, but I recommend adding `axis cs:` then so the line looks like `|- (axis cs: \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})`.

Comment: I reinstalled LaTeX and this time it works with this code. Thanks!